# Convention to install files to /etc/ as non-root?

Tags: sudo, configuration, make, etc, cmake

This question possibly has relevance in both Unix & Linux and Stack Overflow; I'm posting at Unix & Linux first, because I think I'd like to understand the issue from the perspective of Unix/Linux convention, before any specific technical implementation.

I'm writing a standalone hello-world application that has need to read a configuration file, `config.yml`.
I've been advised that convention is to install the file at `/etc/hello-world/config.yml`.
Now, I noticed that `/etc/` has write-privilege by root-only:

```
$ ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 127 root root 12288 Feb 14 21:16 /etc
```

I did not set up this Linux PC, but a competent Linux admin did, so I assume this is standard/convention to have `/etc/` writable only by user `root` and readable by everyone else.

So my question is: how can the install mechanism of my hello-world application (`cmake && make install`) install anything in `/etc/` if the processes are being run by a non-root user?

In terms of *implementation*, my "install mechanism" is an `install` statement in my  `CMakeLists.txt`, e.g.:

```
install (FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.yml
  DESTINATION /etc/hello-world/config.yml)
```

...but again, since I will be running `make install` as non-root, this will fail.

Again, I'm asking the question from the perspective of learning Unix/Linux *convention* -- I imagine this is a common scenario: a lone developer wants to install his config files to "standard" locations, which I was advised is `/etc/your-app/your-config`. So how does he go about doing so if `/etc/` is writable only by root?

Is it understood that `make install` should only be done by root, or a sudo-privileged user, e.g. `sudo make install`?
Or is it not correct that config-files should be installed to (a subdirectory of) `/etc/`?
Or should `/etc/`'s permissions allow writing by "others"?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, by design.

Your app should store **per-user** configs somewhere in the user's home directory, *e.g.* `~/.config/your_app/config.yml`

**System-level** configuration files are what belong in `/etc/`. Like if your app had a local server somewhere on the network that all users should connect to. *That* file would be installed by the System Admin along with the application.

See also [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) and [LSB](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml).

Comment: My hello-world application would run as a service that ran a web server, therefore would be serving connecting clients...so in that case, would its config files meet what you call "system-level" config file? If yes, then it sounds like convention is that a System Admin would install the config-file and/or the application itself -- is that correct?

Comment: is it an application or a service?

Comment: "application would run as a service that ran a web server" that's nowhere in your original question. If it's going to be on standard web server ports (80, 443) then again (by design) you _must_ do this as `root`.